# facebook api python get birthday

Tags: python, facebook, api

I am using the facebook API in python to extract some information about users. I need to get users birthdays but I am only able to get my friend(s) birthday(s). Is there a way to get anyone's bday or is that a privacy setting?

my code:

```
import facebook

token = "CAAErZAZAHDByABADxr766............................."

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("Any_user")
print profile['birthday']
```

Comment: of coarse you cant ... that would totally violate privacy ..

Comment: @JoranBeasley I assumed, but I just wanted to be sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Facebook API, but I'd assume not, unless it's public.  Privacy settings don't (or at least shouldn't) go away because you're using an API instead of their browser interface.